# MS Access 2010 SQL Select Into Calculated Column Issue

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access-2010, powerpivot, select-into

I have a pretty extensive Union query with calculated columns that I'm trying to just "paste values" into a table through a separate SELECT INTO query. I get the error below when executing the query. Is there any way around this without using VBA?

“Calculated columns are not allowed in SELECT INTO statements.”

For context:
Normally, I'd be able to link up to the union query through PowerPivot in Excel but for some reason PowerPivot does not recognize the union query. If I export the union query then import as a table, PowerPivot recognizes it.

Comment: @HansUp Are you referring to the SELECT INTO query or the source query that I want in a table?

Comment: @HansUp "Is this like what you have?: You have Query1 which is a UNION query. And other query, Query2, which is a SELECT INTO query intended to save the results from Query1 as a new table. Query1 runs without error, but Query2 throws the error."       EXACTLY!

Comment: OK.  So if you create an empty table with with appropriate fields to receive the values returned by *Query1*, can you then run an "append query" to load the *Query1* results into that table?  `INSERT INTO YourTable (<field list>) SELECT <field list> FROM Query1`

Comment: @HansUp It worked! Sorry for the delay. It's a complex query. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @HansUp for the help.

I set up a blank table with the appropriate headers from the UNION query and used an INSERT INTO query rather than a SELECT INTO to get the UNION query data into the table.